# Node, Express, 404 error / cannot get route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an Express app and having some issues with routing. All of my routes are working perfectly except for one.

I have a route/admin/products that works:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/admin/products", (req, res) => {
    res.send(productsIndexTemplate({ products }));
});
```

Another route/admin/products/new that also works:

```
router.get("/admin/products/new", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.send(productsNewTemplate({}))
});
```

but this route doesn't work:

```
router.get('/admin/products/:id/edit'), async (req, res) => { 
    const product = await productsRepo.getOne(req.params.id);
    res.send(productsEditTemplate( {product} ));
};
```

I get the proper URL (meaning that I get a proper ID in the url so the req.params.id is not undefined or null but I have this message:

```
Cannot GET /admin/products/08a4dc4f/edit
```

I don't think the problem is with my code as the other routes are working except the last one.

Comment: Is your `productsEditTemplate` correct? It might be that it doesn't find the file

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a try{}catch(e){} block to see if the actions are working properly. Also, can you confirm that the route is triggered in the backend? If you do a console.log( req.params.id) you see the id?

Answer (score 1):

You added a parenthesis(closing bracket)  in route.

```
router.get('/admin/products/:id/edit'), async (req, res) => { //<---- Your error is in this line. After edit you added closing bracket.
    const product = await productsRepo.getOne(req.params.id);
    res.send(productsEditTemplate( {product} ));
};
```

Replace with below code.

```
router.get('/admin/products/:id/edit', async (req, res) => { 
    const product = await productsRepo.getOne(req.params.id);
    res.send(productsEditTemplate( {product} ));
});
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the issue! I have been staring at it for so long and I didn't even see it ....